# Chrome Sender Sample App

Tags: android, google-chrome, casting, chromecast, sender

I am trying to make an app for personal use that has the same functionality of the chrome sender sample app (https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-chrome)

The only thing I am trying to change is the "SAMPLE APP" at the top of the casted screen. I have registered my device via the console and created a new custom receiver in this receiver i have included a URL for a Google drive HTML document I made (Just a black HTML page: https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B7IBRkdKpfYSRmZCYzJaTUpDamM

I then took my newly acquired application id and injected it into the code replacing the Googles sample app ID... I am using Mongoose to host the webpage locally and after I type a message I get no option to connect to my cast device.
Also I have entered my computers local IP and port number (where I am hosting the sender app) under sender details (chrome). I have tried Google's sample code and it works fine the only thing I have changed is the application ID.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you rebooted your chromecast? Give that  a try.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing a week ago and the google drive's trick (to host an html page) doesn't work for me.

Your receiver app (your black html page) need to be accessible online, otherwise it's impossible to connect your sender app to your cast device.

So you must put your html file on a server. Do you have a personnal server to host it ?

I pushed your html file on my server and it's connected to a new App ID. Can you try with this App ID : E46DA3D7

If it's working then your probleme is really Google Drive hosting.

Let me know ;)

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't use a stylized receiver I made the mistake of using a custom receiver. Works fine with stylized receiver. Hosting on Google Drive.

Comment: That's a good news ! I'm only working with custom receiver so i didn't try with stylized receiver.